want to generate memory based rag with vector stores for storing documents
I'm working on building a memory-based chat system that utilizes vector retrieval for multiple users across multiple sessions. I'm using LangChain, OpenAI, and ChromaDB in Python.
My current implementation involves integrating LangChain's VectorDBQA with OpenAI for language processing and ChromaDB for vector retrieval. However, I'm encountering challenges in properly integrating these components, especially accessing VectorDB and resolving errors when invoking the system.
Here's a summary of what I've attempted so far:

Initialized VectorDB and created a retriever.
Configured a ChatPromptTemplate with ChatOpenAI model for conversational prompts.
Set up a ChatMessageHistory for managing user sessions.
Tried integrating VectorDBQA with ChatOpenAI within a RunnableWithMessageHistory object.

Despite these efforts, I'm struggling with accessing VectorDB with runnablechain in langchain, and encountering errors during invocation.
Could someone guide me on integrating LangChain's VectorDBQA with OpenAI and ChromaDB for a memory-based chat system in Python? Any insights or suggestions on resolving the mentioned issues would be greatly appreciated.
from langchain.chains import VectorDBQA
from langchain.llms import OpenAI

# Now we can load the persisted database from disk, and use it as normal. 
vectordb = Chroma(persist_directory=persist_directory, embedding_function=embedding)
qa = VectorDBQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="stuff", vectorstore=vectordb)
retriever = vectordb.as_retriever(k=4)

from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_openai.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

model = ChatOpenAI()

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        (
            "system",
            "You're an assistant who's good at {ability}. Respond in 20 words or fewer",
        ),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", "{input}"),
    ]
)
runnable = prompt | model

from langchain_core.runnables import ConfigurableFieldSpec
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import ChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.chat_history import BaseChatMessageHistory
from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
from langchain_openai.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7)


store = {}


def get_session_history(user_id: str, conversation_id: str) -> BaseChatMessageHistory:
    if (user_id, conversation_id) not in store:
        store[(user_id, conversation_id)] = ChatMessageHistory()
    return store[(user_id, conversation_id)]


with_message_history = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    runnable = retriever|llm,
    get_session_history=get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="query",
    history_messages_key="history",
    history_factory_config=[
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="user_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="User ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the user.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
        ConfigurableFieldSpec(
            id="conversation_id",
            annotation=str,
            name="Conversation ID",
            description="Unique identifier for the conversation.",
            default="",
            is_shared=True,
        ),
    ],
)

user_id = "user123"
conversation_id = "conv456"
question = "What is the capital of France?"

# Invoke the chain with the user's question and conversation context
response = with_message_history.invoke(
    {"query": question},
     config={"configurable": {"user_id": user_id, "conversation_id": conversation_id}},
)

So, I have two questions.

How can I generate a memory based rag with vector retrieval?
How do I use runnable chain with openai and chromadb to do this?

